# how to get a toyota sieanna rpms down

Tags: vacuum

replaced the spark plugs , wires and the plennam gasket on a 2000toyota sieanna and now running at 2000 rpms.i tried to find a vaccum leak , but no ,luck.I am wandering if i need to relearn this high idling

Comment: Its something you did while replacing the plenum gasket.

Comment: Tks I’ll look again but do not have any codes